# Redirect after user changes password

Tags: redirect, login, password

I'm doing a custom form where the user can change is password. 
After submission and if the password is according to the rules I save the new one, overriding the old one, to the database, delete the cache and do the logout and signon of the user. 
Right now after that it's redirecting do the homepage, but what I want to do after is to redirect the user to a specific page, where I show a message, instead of going to the homepage.
Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any piece of code to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you have a custom form, I am assuming you are not going to use WordPress default 'reset password' functionality.

You can use [wp_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) or [wp_safe_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect) to redirect to a specific page after a particular condition (e.g. if the password is changed successfully)

Comment: Thank you! I was making some mistake and that was why it wasn't working correctly, and with your help I found the mistake. And yes you'te assuming correctly, I'm not using the 'reset password' funcionality